# Declaration file for nested modules

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I have a project with a Node JS module inside `foo/bar.js`. Now I'm writing a TypeScript module in `src/mymod.ts` which should import `foo/bar.js`. How do I write a declarations file for `foo/bar.js` module? Where should the declarations file go?

I've tried placing a declarations file in `foo/bar.d.ts` but when I `import * as bar from "../foo/bar"` in my TypeScript module, I get the following error:

```
File '/tmp/my_proj/foo/bar.d.ts' is not a module.
```

This is my `tsconfig.json` file

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowJs": true,
    "outDir": "./dist/",
    "target": "es2017",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "strictNullChecks": true
  },
  "include": [
    "./src/"
  ]
}
```

This is my declaration file:

```
// Type definitions for bar
declare module "bar" {
  function fun1(n: number) : number;
  function fun2(n: number) : number;
  function fun3(n: number) : number;
}
```

Comment: Looks to me like `bar.d.ts` isn't declared properly, if you don't have any `export` statements in it, it isn't a module which would explain the error - if you can include that file in your question I might be able to help more.

Comment: @Gerrit0 forgot to add the declaration file. Added now, thanks

Comment: @Gerrit0 So, I've managed to fix this issue by removing the `module` construct and adding `export` to the function (I have several functions in fact). I thought a module was exported automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is fixed if I change the declarations file to the following:

```
export function fun1(n: number) : number;
export function fun2(n: number) : number;
export function fun3(n: number) : number;
```

I've came up with this solution when I've read @Gerrit0's comment. If someone can write a better answer with explanations I will change the answer.